# Can't run windows executable in Wine on Mac

Tags: macos, wine

Getting this output: http://pastebin.com/PzQULCtx

Trying to run program called Chess Position Trainer with Wine on my Mac. I have tried VMs but they make the program run way too slow. A friend suggested Wine but I'm having trouble getting to running. I made a prefix with WineBottler to create the app. When I click on the .exe it bounces on my dock for a bit and then closes. When I try to run it through my terminal it gives me that above output. Tried googling this issue but not gleaning anything from my search. Any ideas?

Comment: You’re missing a file. Namely, `DevExpress.BonusSkins.v13.2.dll` (or something).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running an existing application, not about programming.

Comment: Seconding icktoofay; I recommend this question be moved to Super User.

Comment: Ok, feel free to close it, I just didn't know where else to turn to. Thanks for the input nonetheless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the location of the Wine installation by running the program directly, one of the optional File paths is the location of the Wine or for mac you should be using the new version WineBottler which is now trademarked for Mac OS X and included Wine and Winebottler. Once you run the program directly your .exe will be in the system files in the same way Windows would store the files under Wine-1.7/Program Files. You might want to reinstall so that you have an easily accessible folder. Make sure to delete all Wine Folders first if you do so. Right now I'm trying to get serial bus and internet functionality within my applications and the new version includes a list of optional services called winetricks that can be applied from the menu, but right now I'm staring at a seemingly hung DOT NET 3.5 SP1 which I'm probably going to let run all day because if it's installing service packs, I've seen those take weeks on old Windows computers.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help me, I'll look into this